# java.lang.NullPointerException at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish

I'm always getting an error after my app is deployed to the production server. In my test environment everything works fine.

Here is the stacktrace from the glassfish log:

```
[2015-09-28T15:57:56.857+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=36 _ThreadName=http-listener-2(2)] [timeMillis: 1443448676857] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:26)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:28)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:665)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
]]
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"    version="3.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/index.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
  <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>-1</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_ID_PRODUCTION_MODE</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.VIEW_UNIQUE_IDS_CACHE_ENABLED</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.SAVE_STATE_WITH_VISIT_TREE_ON_PSS</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>pepper-grinder</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I'm using JSF 2.2 with Primefaces 4.0. Thanks for your tips!

Comment: As commented, JSF 2.3 is not out yet. Which version of Primefaces?

Comment: Primefaces 4.0. And I meant 2.2. (typo)

Comment: Do you have a faces-config.xml? If yes, please add this and your web.xml to the question.

Comment: First thing to always, always, always do is to post ["java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:26)"](https://www.google.nl/search?q=java.lang.NullPointerException+at+org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:26)) in a search engine, you get hits... check them

Comment: I dont have a faces-config and I added my web.xml to my question

Answer (score 0):

Looking at these two frames:

```
at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:26)
at org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContext.release(PrimeFacesContext.java:28)
```

And the source code:

```
24 @Override
25 public void release() {
26     RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().release();
27
28     wrapped.release();
29 }
```

(Reference: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.primefaces/primefaces/4.0/org/primefaces/context/PrimeFacesContext.java)

It looks to me like something has created a `PrimeFacesContext` that wraps `null`, and then wrapped that with another `PrimeFacesContext`.  Clearly, it is wrong to wrap a `null` like that, since an NPE is inevitable if `release` is called.

Check your app code to see if it is responsible for doing this.